# Jquery mobile swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe

I have tabs within a dynamic page. The tabs works great when pressed but I would like to add a swipe function to it so that users can also swipe to next tab.

Here is my attempt of trying to make the swipe function work

```
function goToMatchDetailPage(matchHome, matchAway){
    first_part_id = matchHome.substring(0,2);
    sec_part_id = matchAway.substring(0,2);
    var id = first_part_id.concat(sec_part_id);
    //create the html template
    var matchPage = $("<div data-role='page' data-url=dummyUrl><div data-role='header'><h1>"
      + matchHome + "</h1></div><div data-role='content'><div data-role='tabs'>"
  + "<div data-role='navbar'>"
  +  "<ul>"
  +    "<li><a href='#fragment-1'>" + matchHome + "</a></li>"
  +   "<li><a href='#fragment-2'>" + matchAway + "</a></li>"
  +  "</ul>"
  + "</div>"
  + "<div id='fragment-1'>"
  +  "<p>This is the content of the tab 'One', with the id fragment-1.</p>"
  + "</div>"
  + "<div id='fragment-2'>"
  +  "<p>This is the content of the tab 'Two', with the id fragment-2.</p>"
  + "</div></div></div>");

    //append the new page to the page contanier
    matchPage.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);

    //go to the newly created page
    $.mobile.changePage(matchPage);
```

**Here is the ppart that doesn't work**

```
$(function(){
// Bind the swipeleftHandler callback function to the swipe event on div.box
$( "div" ).on( "swipeleft", swipeleftHandler );

// Callback function references the event target and adds the 'swipeleft' class to it
function swipeleftHandler( event ){
//go to the newly created page
    $.mobile.changePage('#fragment-2');
 }
});

}
```

!

Comment: did you try `$( "div" ).bind( "swipeleft", swipeleftHandler );`

Comment: Using the `document.ready` function is a bad idea when you're not loading the page for each button click, check-out the documentation for events: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/api/events.html. When you create new elements, your initial binding will not affect those elements, so you have to re-bind to the new elements or use a delegated event handler. There is a ton of information about this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Tried both still didn't work

Comment: You want to change pages or change between tabs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using event delegation:

Because fragment-1 does not exist at the time you are creating the handler, you assign the handler to the document and delegate it to any child elements called fragment-1 that exist now or will exist in the future.

To make it more generic, you can assign classes to the div and delegate to the class instead of an id...

> **UPDATE**

You can't use changepage to go between tabs, instead use the tabs widget active property(http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active):

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
   $("#btngo").on("click", function(){
        goToMatchDetailPage('Liverpool', 'Southhampton');    
    });

    $(document).on("swipeleft", "#fragment-1", function(){    
           $(this).parents("div [data-role=tabs]").tabs( "option", "active", 1 );    
    } );
        $(document).on("swiperight", "#fragment-2", function(){    
           $(this).parents("div [data-role=tabs]").tabs( "option", "active", 0 );    
    } );         
});
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/DZfBC/1/)**

The swipe code is assigned to the document and then delegated to the dynamic div. When you swipe on a tab div, we find its parent that is the tab widget container and then set its active tab option to change tabs.

Comment: I thought this would work myself but nothing appears to be on the screen now. Everything is in one function do you think it should be separate?

Comment: You've used `$(function(){});` :O

Comment: @Omar, i just left $(function(){ out of laziness ;)

Comment: Help me out mate. I removed the function and the }); but a blank screen still shows

Comment: @Omar, I overcame my laziness and updated the answer with demo and no $(function()... I hope you are happy now ;)

Comment: I'm really sorry but when i swipe on your demo it doesn't work. the tab works but the swipe doesn't. Thanks for effort

Comment: For me in Chrome, if I swipe on the text it changes tabs, the tab divs are only about 50 px high because there is only one line of content, so make sure you swipe near the text.

Comment: Ahh I see. It works. Just have to try and fix something else now lol. Cool.

Answer (score 0):

I'm easier than the others.. It's not the whole solution, but you can get my point.

Option 1

```
   $(document).on("swipeleft", '#page1', function () {
        $('#fragment-2').trigger('click');
                });
```

Option 2

```
   $(document).on("swipeleft", '#page1', function () {
        $(this).find("div [data-role=tabs]").tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
                });
```

Not sure about which one is better thought :)